# Best practice to separate Backend / Frontend with single Laravel4 installation?

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel-4

I would like to hear your tips from someone who already got a real experience with his folder structure he worked with.

Coming from *CodeIgniter*, I'm trying now to figure out what would be best way to create a **Backend** (CMS) and **Frontend** (frontpage) ?

Here are couple app structures I want to get your critics on, considering that actual version of Laravel is `4.1.28`.

Structure 1

```
WEBAPP
    BACKEND
        app/
        bower_components/
        local_components/
        node_modules/
        public/
        vendor/
        artisan.php
        composer.json
        composer.lock
        CONTRIBUTING.md
        Gruntfile.js
        package.json
        phpunit.xml
        readme.md
        server.php
    FRONTEND
        app/
        bower_components/
        local_components/
        node_modules/
        public/
        vendor/
        artisan.php
        composer.json
        composer.lock
        CONTRIBUTING.md
        Gruntfile.js
        package.json
        phpunit.xml
        readme.md
        server.php
```

Structure 2

```
WEBAPP
    app/
        bootstrap/
        commands/
        config/
        controllers/
        ...
        views/
        filters.php
        routes.php
    cms/
        bootstrap/
        commands/
        config/
        controllers/
        ...
        views/
        filters.php
        routes.php
    bower_components/
    local_components/
    node_modules/
    public/         // This is public for mywebapp.dev
        ...
        index.php
    sub/backend     // This is public for backend.mywebapp.dev
        ...
        index.php
    vendor/
    ...
    server.php
```

Structure 3

```
WEBAPP
    app/
        controllers/
            Backend/
                BackendController.php
            Frontend/
                FrontendController.php
            BaseController.php
        models/
            Backend/
                BackendModel.php
            Frontend/
                FrontendModel.php
            BaseModel.php
        views/
            Backend/
                layout.blade.php
            Frontend/
                layout.blade.php
    bootstrap/
    bower_components/
    local_components/
    public/
        assets/
            backend/
                js/
                css/
            frontend/
                js/
                css/
        index.php
    vendor/
    server.php
```

Also, if you have your own app structure, you are welcome to share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really is a personal preference type of scenario and there is no real correct answer as everyone works in different ways.

I tend to do something similar to:

```
app
    NameSpace // This is your custom namespace, so for my company it would be AffinityCloud. Then load this in your composer.json using PSR-4 autoloading.
        Controllers // I remove the controllers folder from the initial app/controllers location and create a new one in my namespace, also moving the BaseController.php file here too.
            Admin // Here go my admin/cms controllers
            Frontend // Here go my frontend controllers
        Exceptions
        Filters
        Handlers
        Models // I also do the same with the models folder as I do with the controllers folder, making sure my Base.php model file is in there. You'll need to remember to remove the references to the old models and controllers folder from app/start/global.php too, as well as remove these references from your composer.json classmap.
        Presenters
        Repositories
        Services
        Utilities
        Validators
```

I also split frontend and backend assets under public/assets in to separate locations as you have done above.

Again, this is just how I like to do it but others my have cleaner solutions or completely different ways of working. As I say, it's really a personal thing.

I find that this is enough separation and organisation for most purposes.

One other thing to keep in mind is that if you have generic code that would work on it's own outside of Laravel, then perhaps you should consider creating a separate composer package for it.